# How to create a WCF client to connect to a web service built using JRuby and sinatra?

Tags: c#, ruby, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a REST web service written in JRuby and uses sinatra. It has one end point.

http://localhost:4567/v4/start.htm

I have a Javascript web client that connects to the JRuby web service.

But now I want to use C# and WCF to connect to this web service instead of using a Javascript web client .

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really want to use a WCF client for that? You'll have to create it "by hand" as WCF has no support for generating clients for REST services. In many cases where the contract isn't available, people end up using a general-purpose HTTP library such as HttpWebRequest or WebClient. If you want to use a WCF client for that, you'll need to create a [ServiceContract] interface and add the methods which map to the service.

Answer (score 0):

The classic model of using WCF in the client assumes SOAP and the availability of WSDL - neither of which are true for a REST service. You have a couple of options:

1. Hand craft the equivalent REST style service contract using
   [WebGet]/[WebInvoke] and use WebChannelFactory to create a proxy
2. Look at the [REST Starter Kit Preview 2](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest) or the new [Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) where you
   will find a class called HttpClient for invoking a REST service